# Is there an easy way to prevent DelayedConfirmationView to react on swipe?

Tags: android, wear-os

Basically when I move through the fragments in GridViewPager, if I swipe touching the DelayedConfirmationView, it is triggered.
I thought that one solution could be intercepting all touches in the GridViewPager and try to figure if it was a swipe, but it sounds very much like reinventing the wheel.
I want to believe that there is a wheel taking care of this already... :)

BTW: I think the DelayedConfirmationView (like many other things) are just not finished in the Wear APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find good solution for this issue too, that's why I implemented simple workaround. I added clickable layout-wrapper.

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/clickable_hack_lt"
android:layout_width="110dp"
android:layout_height="110dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="startTimerClick"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp">

<android.support.wearable.view.DelayedConfirmationView
    android:id="@+id/delayed_confirm"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    app:circle_border_color="#992878ff"
    app:circle_border_width="10dp"
    app:circle_radius="60dp"
    app:circle_color="@color/action_button"/>
```

And in your java code you can do smth like this

```
public void startTimerClick(View v) {
  if (!isRunning) {
      mDelayedView.setListener(listener);
      listener.onTimerSelected(v);
  }
}
```